# Redirect one subdomain page to a domain page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I want to redirect my subdomain registration page to my domain registration page in .htaccess for wordpress multisite. I am using the below code but it does not work.

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 http://sub.domain.com/register/(.*) http://domain.com/register//$1
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `mod_alias(redirectmatch)` in that way. You have to use `mod_rewrite` if you want to match based on the hostname.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)$ http://domain.com/register/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the .htaccess is in the root of sub.domain.com then you can just do this but using the absolute path.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/register/(.*)$ http://domain.com/register/$1
```

Comment: By the way, if I need to redirect two subdomains to the registration page, should I repeat the last line of the code?
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)$ http://domain.com/register/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: No... but you should make that a new question. Accept this answer since it's resolved and then I can help you add more to your rule if you need it in another question.

Comment: I notice that you've not accepted the answer on any of your previous questions. You really should accept the answers when someone provides you the assistance this is why. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308899

Comment: I looked for accept answer but I don't have this option. I would defenitly accept your answer as I gave it +1. The problem is that I don't see accept an answer. I only see Share, edit and flag.

Comment: Hi, I saw it now. Thanks. I accepted it. Did not know about it previously. I apologize for any inconvenience from my side.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found it. Good luck

Comment: Hi Panama, the function above is no longer working after the latest update of buddypress. Please help.